# Error uploading Django project to Digital Ocean

Tags: python, django

I've a Bad gateway error whenever I try and upload my Django project to Digital ocean.

I was following this guide https://pythonprogramming.net/django-web-server-publish-tutorial/ but I didn't update Django, I'm using version 1.8.7. Do I need to change the secret key on the server to the secret key on my project?

This is the Nginx error message

```
2018/01/10 17:07:58 [error] 2210#2210: *5 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 86.167.15.195, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/", host: "159.65.16.251"
2018/01/10 17:08:45 [error] 2210#2210: *7 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 86.167.15.195, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream:
```

I've changed allowed hosts in the settings file to = [159.65.16.251]

Do I also need to change this our just leave it out?

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ip_addresses()
```

Url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^', include('personal.urls')),
url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
url(r'^writing/', include('writing.urls')),
]
```

This is my nginx config

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
worker_connections 768;
# multi_accept on;
}

http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
SSL Settings
##

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


mail {
# See sample authentication script at:
# http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript

auth_http localhost/auth.php;
pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";

server {
listen     localhost:110;
protocol   pop3;
proxy      on;
}

server {
    listen     localhost:143;
    protocol   imap;
proxy      on;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work I just had to do  manage.py migrate from the server.